# make failed in installing intl on php 5.3.8 in linux

Tags: php

while executing a pecl install intl on linux i am getting this error please help

```
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:92: error: 
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:96: error: 
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:101: error: 
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:107: error:
make: *** [collator/collator_class.lo] "
ERROR: `make' failed
```

on php site also there is no solution for this, what i found is that pecl is taking the old version or 32bit intl file. my php version is PHP 5.3.8 (cli)

Comment: This would normally be fine to migrate to Server Fault, but it's been asked there (unfortunately without resolution).

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like the same issue (Installing/enabling PHP Pecl Intl extension on CentOs 5)](https://serverfault.com/questions/210889/installing-enabling-php-pecl-intl-extension-on-centos-5)

There is no accepted answer, but you can try what's suggested and tell if it works.